# Jqgrid - How to display selected rowdata of first grid in vertical columns in second grid

Tags: jqgrid

I have a situation where if I select the row of first grid its header and values should be vertically assigned in second jqgrid. I was able to get the rowdata from onselectrow but how should I pass this to second grid and display them vertically.

If anyone have any idea about how to achieve it ..I will really appreciate...Thanks!

Comment: It's better that you include JavaScript code and the pictures or better the demo (in jsfiddle, for example), which reproduces the problem.

Comment: @ Oleg thank you so much for responding to my question. I did solved my problem.